Gulp for compiling SASS and automatic updates
Earlier on I had a security policy issue on scripting which I was able to resolve.
I have tried to follow gulp documentation on the installation and compilation of sass and also a few YouTube tutorials. Now I keep on getting " Task never defined: sass" when running gulp build_styles function.
`    'use strict';
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));

function build_styles() {
      return gulp.src('./app/sass/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
};``


It appears the error is correct, you need to define and export the task, you should run the gulp task below your function:-
gulp.task('build_styles', build_styles);

Then you should be able to run your gulp task. You also have 2 backticks in your code which you probably should remove (``)

To clarify since it looks like you're probably running gulp sass to get that error you're seeing, once you've added this you'll call gulp build_styles

That worked but then when  I tried to run the default task I got "AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
"
